# Why do we need MAP_PRIVATE flag when mapping memory?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying map anonymously a page of memory. Here is it:

```
mov rax, 0x09   ; SYS_mmap
mov rdi, 0x00   ; addr is NULL
mov rsi, 0x8000 ; x86 page_size
mov rdx, 0x02   ; PROT_WRITE
mov r10, 0x20   ; MAP_ANONYMOUS
mov r8, -1      ; fd = -1
mov r9, 0x00    ; offset = 0
syscall

mov [rax], dword -2 ; Segmentation fault, rax = -22
```

This is SegFaulted. But when I add `MAP_PRIVATE` to flags it works ok:

```
mov rax, 0x09   ; SYS_mmap
mov rdi, 0x00   ; addr is NULL
mov rsi, 0x8000 ; x86 page_size
mov rdx, 0x02   ; PROT_WRITE
mov r10, 0x22   ; MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE 
mov r8, -1      ; fd = -1
mov r9, 0x00    ; offset = 0
syscall

mov [rax], dword -2 ; Now it works ok, rax = 0x7ffff7ff2000
```

I don't quite why `mmap` fails why we map anonymously without specifying the `MAP_PRIVATE` flag?

Comment: `man mmap`: _"including exactly one [...] MAP_SHARED [...] MAP_PRIVATE"_. But it fails even with `MAP_SHARED`, you can't share anonymous mappings since nobody else can open it anyway.

Comment: It seems that your code does not check for the syscall returning an exit code. Detecting a situation when exit code != 0 will increase robustness of your program, and will also help to debug it, as syscall error codes are documented at least in kernel sources.

Comment: @Jester Understood. Thanks!

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov Agree. But in that case I just wanted to check the behavior of `mmap`.

Comment: @Jester Just checked with `MAP_SHARED`. Worked ok for me. Did you get `Segmentation Fault`?

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov: Using `strace` to see syscall return values is easier than writing error-check code by hand, especially in asm.  For experimentation, I always use `strace` instead of writing error handling.  If writing an actual program for future use, I do it in C and use `perror` on error.  Anyway, the problem with this question is not including `strace` output, as well as double-checking that the mapping is usable by storing to it.  (Because it's easy to have some other bug by accident, and segfault on that.)

Comment: @St.Antario yeah I messed up the flags, `MAP_SHARED` works too.

Comment: @PeterCordes Did not know about `strace`. Just tried it in the seg fault case. Looks very useful...

Comment: If you didn't know that, go read the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for more debugging tips.  `strace` is an essential tool for systems programming, and for figuring out what programs are doing when you didn't write them (e.g. as a sysadmin figuring out where something is looking for config files).

Comment: @PeterCordes nice trick with `strace`! As of error checking, it is just me who was taught to never postpone the addition of error checking code in system programming, as "I will do it later" always turns to "never".

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov: I'm only talking about cases where I plan to *never* add error checking, e.g. as part of an experiment to test something else, which I'm not planning to develop into a program that I maintain long term.  Because of the existence of `strace` and other debugging tools, there are many such cases when creating experiments / microbenchmarks.  I agree that if you're writing something for real use, you shouldn't skip the error checking in the first version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need `MAP_PRIVATE`, you need one of `MAP_PRIVATE` or `MAP_SHARED`.

> The flags argument determines whether updates to the mapping are
>          visible to other processes mapping the same region, and whether
>          updates are carried through to the underlying file.  This behavior is
>          determined by including exactly one of the following values in flags:
>
> `MAP_SHARED`
>                                 Share this mapping.  [...]
>
> `MAP_PRIVATE`
>                   Create a private copy-on-write mapping. [...]

---

[`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) lets you choose how to propagate any change made to the mapped region:

- `MAP_PRIVATE` backed up by a file
  No updates are visible to other processes mapping the same file.
  No updates are written to the backing file.
  Updates are made to a [COW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) page.

  Useful to process the content of a file in-place.
- `MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS` (e.g. *not* backed up by a file)
  There is no file to update.
  Updates are made to a COW page.

  Useful to allocate memory, not shared with forked processes.
- `MAP_SHARED` backed up by file
  Updates are visible to other processes.
  Updates are propagated to the backing file.

  Useful to transform a file.
  Useful to share a memory area with other processes using a name (see [shm_open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html)).
- `MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS` (e.g. *not* backed up by a file)
  Updates are visible to all the processes with the same region mapped.
  There is no file to update.

  Useful to share an internal memory area with forked processes.

Comment: With `MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS`, is it actually possible for any other process to map "the same region"?  It's anonymous, so there's no "name" for it.  Is there any practical difference between `MAP_SHARED` and `MAP_PRIVATE` when used with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` (including any weird corner cases?)

Comment: @PeterCordes If the parent maps it and then forks the children will have it mapped and shared with each other and the parent. I've not tested it but found a QA here on SO about it. It's consistent with the behaviour of `fork`.

Comment: This short video: [Simple Shared Memory in C (mmap)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPV6b8BUwxM) demonstrates exactly this scenario.